# Docker image build fails. Jupyter command "nbconvert" cannot find ipython notebook

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, jupyter

I have created a Dockerfile with the purpose of executing a Jupyter notebook inside Docker. It looks like the following

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 \
    python3-pip

RUN pip3 install jupyter

WORKDIR /home/me/JupyterOneClick/
RUN pwd

RUN jupyter nbconvert --to python Hello.ipynb
RUN python Hello.py
#CMD ["python","Hello.py"]
```

But, i am given an error when building this image (docker build -t jupyter:latest .)

Step 6 converts the jupyter notebook to a python file, and step 7 executes that python file.

> Step 6/7 : RUN jupyter nbconvert --to python Hello.ipynb
>    ---> Running in 8516a27588f6
>   [NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern 'Hello.ipynb' matched no files
>   This application is used to convert notebook files (*.ipynb) to various other
>   formats.

The jupyter notebook is stored in /home/me/JupyterOneClick.

At this point, the build process stops.

I also tried to move step 6 and 7 into a shell script, and run the script from Dockerfile, through which i am able to build the image, but cannot run it,  as it cannot find the shell script.

> The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x ./script.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1

Can anyone tell me how do i fix this? I am a beginner, but from what i can understand, RUN creates a new temporary container because of which it is not able to find the file.

For anyone who is wondering, i am not using kubeflow or JupyterHub as they allow for a new development enviromnment, and i have to deploy an existing notebook.

Comment: You have to add the Hello.ipynb to ```Dockerfile``` with ADD before you run the jupyter command. By the way the if you have an existing notebook, you can use volumes and attached it to container to can use with JupyterHub.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I figured i had to COPY the file to the container before i ran the dockerfile. But, can you please elaborate on how can i use volumes to attach them to containers? I asked the same question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054646/automated-deployment-of-existing-jupyter-notebook-to-kubernetes , can you maybe take a look and answer it?

Answer (score 1):

Im not an expert but it seems like you forgot the copy statement.
Use `COPY ./Hello.ipynb /Hello.ipynb`and instead of `-- to python` you should use `-- to script`